# Format number to specific number of digits and custom punctuation

Tags: r, regex

I have this `DF1`:

```
           cpf 
702.464.462-18    
067.282.769-71    
017.811.255-03    
806.392.831-87    
074.256.613-73    
080.405.147-03
```

And this other one `DF2`:

```
          cpf   
1:  6685540966   
2:  1301301922   
3: 80673503020   
4: 13575505705  
5: 36752823847  
6:  1756061459
```

I'd like to format these numbers, so the `DF2` can be the same as the `DF1`, like this:

```
          cpf   
1:  066.855.409-66   
2:  013.013.019-22   
3:  806.735.030-20   
4:  135.755.057-05  
5:  367.528.238-47  
6:  017.560.614-59
```

So basically i need to transform them into a 11 digit number with 0's, and specify the punctuiation like that.
Any ideas how to do it?

EDIT:
Using the `str_pad` from the`stringr` packaged i did:

```
str_pad(DF2$cpf, 11, pad = "0")
```

And it worked. However i don't know how to set the punctuation.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: i've tried format, but couldn't do it... and have literally no idea how to do the custom punctuation.

Comment: ...and i'm in a hurry (as usual)

Comment: if your data will always have 11 digits after you pad with 0s, you can use a combo of `substr` and `paste0` to recombine the string to format it. Not very elegant though

Answer (score 0):

We can use `formatC`

```
cpf <- c(6685540966, 1301301922, 80673503020, 13575505705, 36752823847, 1756061459)
formatC(x = cpf / 100, 
            digits = 2, 
            width = 12, 
            decimal.mark = "-", 
            big.mark = ".", 
            flag = "0", 
            format = "f")
#[1] "066.855.409-66"
#[2] "013.013.019-22"
#[3] "806.735.030-20"
#[4] "135.755.057-05"
#[5] "367.528.238-47"
#[6] "017.560.614-59"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by formatting the number with the format() (AKA pretty() function), then padding the zero.

> ... specify the punctuiation like that.

```
#Sample data
DF2<- c(6685540966, 1301301922, 80673503020, 13575505705, 36752823847, 1756061459)

DF3<-format(DF2/100, 11, digits=10, decimal.mark="-", big.mark=".")

[1] "66.855.409-66"  "13.013.019-22"  "806.735.030-20" "135.755.057-05" "367.528.238-47" "17.560.614-59"
```

> i need to transform them into a 11 digit number with 0's

This is called "pad with leading zeros". `str_pad()` from `stringr` works similarly to paste, making it explicit that you want to pad numbers.

```
library(stringr)
DF4<-str_pad(DF3, 14, pad = "0")

[1] "066.855.409-66" "013.013.019-22" "806.735.030-20" "135.755.057-05" "367.528.238-47" "017.560.614-59"
```